# What photo organizer software can store keywords/tags in EXIF without mangling other EXIF metadata?

Tags: software-recommendation, photos, folders

I would like to organize my photos into folders with labels/tags/keywords, possibly also with captions or descriptions for each photo. I would like that information put into the EXIF metadata of the photo files, so that it can be read by other programs (like digikam or f-spot, for instance). I would NOT like to overwrite other unrelated metadata (like Picasa does with various fields).

Answer (score 1):

[digikam](http://www.digikam.org/download?q=download/binary/) can do this, but requires compilation via macports.